How to create a directed network from a matrix?
Say that we have such a matrix:

The 1 indicates a direction from the row to the column, a 2 means a bi-direction, a zero no-relationship (diagonal is by default always 0). I would like then to build a network that represents these relationships, so, for example, one-side arrow from D to A, two-side arrow between A and B, and so on. How to do this using the library igraph?

See the manual: https://r.igraph.org/reference/index.html

Why do you use 2 to represent reciprocal edges? This information is already contained in the matrix anyway, and is inconsistent with the standard concept of adjacency matrices.

You can turn your (custom?) graph representation to adjacency matrix by replacing twos with ones, from there it's just igraph::graph_from_adjacency_matrix()
library(igraph)
m <- matrix(c(0,2,1,0,
              2,0,0,0,
              0,1,0,1,
              1,0,0,0),
            nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE,
            dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:4],LETTERS[1:4]))
m
#>   A B C D
#> A 0 2 1 0
#> B 2 0 0 0
#> C 0 1 0 1
#> D 1 0 0 0

# relpace 2s with 1s and you'll have adjacency matrix
m[m == 2] <- 1
m      
#>   A B C D
#> A 0 1 1 0
#> B 1 0 0 0
#> C 0 1 0 1
#> D 1 0 0 0

plot(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m))


Created on 2024-06-02 with reprex v2.1.0

Simple and effective!

You can use simplify first before plot, e.g.,
graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m) %>%
    simplify() %>%
    plot()

which gives

Otherwise, you will obtain
graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m) %>%
    plot()



Here is a way.
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(tidyverse)
  library(igraph)
})

m <- matrix(
  c(0, 2, 1, 1,
    2, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0),
  ncol = 4L,
  byrow = TRUE,
  dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:4], LETTERS[1:4])
)

m %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(id = row.names(.)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) -> df1

head(df1)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   id    name  value
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A     A         0
#> 2 A     B         2
#> 3 A     C         1
#> 4 A     D         1
#> 5 B     A         2
#> 6 B     B         0

# this will repeat the rows with values 2
# and eliminate the zeros
i <- rep(row.names(df1), df1$value)
df1 <- df1[i, ]

g <- split(df1, df1[1:2], drop = TRUE) %>%
  lapply(\(x) {
    if(nrow(x) > 1L) {
      x[2, 1:2] <- x[2, 2:1]
    }
    x
  }) %>%
  do.call(rbind, args = .) %>%
  select(-value) %>% 
  unique() %>%
  graph_from_data_frame() 

plot(g)


Created on 2024-06-02 with reprex v2.1.0

I think edge A-D should be unidirectional.

@ThomasIsCoding You are right, I will delete my answer.
